# Simple read-only locking mechanism

Tags: mysql, database, qt, locking

I'm developing a GUI client for MySQL database using Qt.
GUI consists of several "editors" placed in forms, an editor for table X,Y,Z,etc.
If I need to prevent the users of client from "collective-editing", how do I go about it the simplest? I just couldn't think of a phrase to google to see other people's solutions.
What I see (as a probable solution) is an `in_use` table, where I store the locked table name (`in_use.table`) and the locked row ID (`in_use.id`).
Each time an editor is opened, a "lock" is inserted, each time it's closed - a lock is removed.
What are the potential pitfalls?

Comment: I feel like there are many users who access DB directly with ALL privileges. If I am correct then you are in trouble :-). So just limit direct access to DB as much as possible. Generally speaking there should be kind ONE or very few users and/or applications having direct access to DB. And all locks should be set on client application level.

Comment: @Alex no one accesses DB directly, except the client itself and my workbench. Yes, the only existing *MySQL* user has all the privileges, but  guess what? The access through client is pretty limited (certain tables are R/O)

Comment: You don't need to block records then during editing. In most cases users should not overlap. But if you want to "lock" records just because somebody  had started editing - you can fail and block too much. What will happens if user forgot to save? and locked record got blocked forever? it becomes to complex. You can try to create some flag system just to return some useful warnings to user, or logically separate records which should be used by particular user. But in general I would try to not implement "locking" system

Comment: @Alex because there is only a small amount of users (less than 50) I suspect they *will* overlap. The "everlock" is solved by removing lock after 10 minutes of inactivity from client side

Comment: I don't see how number of users related to possible "conflicts". IMHO these things are not related. Its all depends on the type of work they execute but not their number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lock the table, you can use **LOCK TABLE table_name READ;**

You can also create locks using **GET_LOCK**, check if they're open using **IS FREE LOCK**, and release them using and **RELEASE_LOCK**.

When an editor is opened, you can check whether your manual lock is in use or not by using **GET_LOCK** or **IS FREE LOCK**. After your editor is done, you can use **RELEASE_LOCK** to free up the next person from accessing the editor.

**PITFALLS**: Doing this on the application side presents a couple problems. If the user closes the form, how will you tell the database to release those locks? Example: I am your user and I go to your site/fat client and I click edit to start my work, halfway through my computer crashes and shuts down.

**EDIT**: you can create a number of different locks if you have different use cases and do not want to lock the resources themselves.

See more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock), [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-free-lock), and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock)

Comment: 1. I don't need table locks! I need row locks, more precisely, a lock onto a row in table A with specific ID and all records in tables B&C which have that ID as a foreign key 2. What I meant is not an actual lock in the DB engine, it's rather a "note" for those other connected clients, "this record is currently being edited, do not corrupt!". 3. The example pitfall sounds scary, but if you add a simple inactivity timer, it's gone

Comment: @mekkanizer ah I’m sorry, I read your description as each editor owning a table. I didn’t realize you meant individual records. I think your initial thought will suffice. Whether you control the cleanup job on the application side or MySQL’s event timer, it sounds like you have a sound method for control. I previously implemented something similar where I would mark the record with a user id, no one else could edit it but it would also let the user know who is working on that record.